# Remote validation not working for guid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, remote-validation

```
[Remote("DropDownSelected", "Patient")]
public Guid SexIdentifier { get; set; }



public ActionResult DropDownSelected(object value)
{
    var x = ((Guid)value).ToString();
    string xsd = value.ToString();
    var abc = ControllerContext.Controller;

    if (value == null)
    {
        //value = string.Empty;
    }

    if (value.ToString() == Convert.ToString(Guid.Empty) || value.ToString() == string.Empty)
    {
        return Json(String.Format("0 does not exist."), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your property is called `SexIdentifier` then your action must use the same name for its argument:

```
public ActionResult DropDownSelected(Guid sexIdentifier) 
{
    ...
}
```

Also if you have a default value of the dropdown you could use a nullable `Guid`:

```
public ActionResult DropDownSelected(Guid? sexIdentifier) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: But i need to use this validation for multiple properties
is there any way i can give a common alias name

Comment: You could try reading it from the POST body: `Request.Form[0]`.